# Espresso: matches multiple views in the hierarchy

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have registration dialog and I need to test in using Espresso, but all the time I get error "matches multiple views in the hierarchy".

Part of registration dialog:

```
<com.rey.material.widget.EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint_registration_dialog"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:et_dividerColor="@color/my_primary"
            app:et_dividerHeight="1dp"
            app:et_labelEnable="true"
            app:et_labelTextColor="@color/my_primary"
            app:et_labelTextSize="14sp"
            app:et_supportLines="1"/>
```

My simple code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.input_name))
                .perform(typeText(numberEnter));
```

And the error:

android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: com.zf.openmaticsdetagtive:id/input_name and has content description)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

> +----->EditText{id=2131689737, res-name=input_name, desc=Name, visibility=VISIBLE, width=730, height=64, has-focus=true,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true,
>   editor-info=[inputType=0x1 imeOptions=0x8000005 privateImeOptions=null
>   actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0
>   initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=Name label=null packageName=null
>   fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null ], x=21.0, y=96.0, child-count=2}
>   ****MATCHES****
>
> +------>InternalEditText{id=2131689737, res-name=input_name, desc=Name, visibility=VISIBLE, width=730, height=38, has-focus=true,
>   has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true,
>   is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true,
>   is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false,
>   root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true,
>   editor-info=[inputType=0x1 imeOptions=0x8000005 privateImeOptions=null
>   actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0
>   initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=Name label=null packageName=null
>   fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null ], x=0.0, y=26.0, text=,
>   hint=Name, input-type=1, ime-target=true, has-links=false}
>   ****MATCHES****

I'm sure that I dont have any other element with this id, but what can cause this problem? What is difference between InternalEditText and EditText? May be that I'm using com.rey.material.widget.EditText?
Thanks in advance for any help or hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
It seems like your assumption is correct.
The [Material Lib](https://github.com/rey5137/material/blob/c2bcca413559f13b822c7d1f75a971779a370528/material/src/main/java/com/rey/material/widget/EditText.java#L3691) uses an internal view called `InternalEditText`.

You will need to specify an extra matcher to match the correct view.

Comment: thank you, but how I can do that? It looks like the same. I have already try to add "contentDescription" and try to find view like onView(allOf(withId(R.id.input_name),hasContentDescription()))... But there is still now result

Comment: thank you! You gave me an idea and I used onView(allOf(withId(R.id.input_name),isClickable()))

Comment: Can you please provide an example for the same?